# What’s the “official” way to remove Plone’s Users tab?

Tags: plone

I've got an installation of Plone 4.2.1 running nicely, but visitors to the site can click on the Users tab in the main menu and go straight to a search of all my registered users. Certainly, anonymous visitors are unable to actually list anyone, but I don't want this functionality at all.

What's the Plone way of:

- removing the Users tab from the main menu?
- stopping the URL /Members returning anything except 404?

Are there other effects of this functionality I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Users` tab is only shown because there is a `Members` folder (with the title `Users`) in the root that is publicly visibile.

You have three options to deal with the default; make the `Members` folder private, delete it  altogether, or remove the `index_html` default view.

### Unpublish

You can 'unpublish', retract, the folder workflow to make it private, and anonymous users are then redirected to the login form instead of seeing the user search form:

[image: how to retract the Users folder]

Simply go to the folder, click on the workflow state (`Published`) and choose `Retract`.

### Delete

If you do not need to have per-user folders, you can remove the `Members` folder altogether. You do need to make sure that user folder creation is not enabled first. Go to the Control Panel (click on your username, top right, select `Site Setup`):

[image: Control Panel link]

select `Security`:

[image: Security entry in the CP]

and make sure that `Enable User Folders` is not checked. If it is, uncheck it and save the settings.

Now just delete the `Members` folder; click `Users`, find the `Actions` menu on the right, then select `Delete`:

[image: Users deletion]

then confirm the deletion in the popup:

[image: Users deletion confirmation]

Deletion means *all* users will get a 404 when visiting `/Members` in your site.

### Delete the default view

The `Members` folder contains a `index_html` object that provides the user form search. If all you want to get rid of is this view, you can delete it. If your `Members` folder is still public, visitors *can* see any userfolders that have been created though.

Deleting this view requires going to the ZMI, the Zope Management Interface, navigating to the `Members` folder and deleting the `index_html` object there.

Since this is not really the recommended course of action I'm leaving out the screenshots for this part.

Comment: Does it have to be called "Members" for automatic creation to work? And will retracting it make it disappear from the menu?

Comment: @IainHallam: The menu only shows folders that the current visitor can reach; retracting `Members` means anonymous visitors can no longer see it listed in the bar. The folder can have any id, but you then need to adjust the members tool in the ZMI. That's `Site Setup` -> `Zope Management Interface` -> `portal_membership` -> bottom of the form (section title `Set members folder`).

Answer (score 3):

You can just delete the Users folder.

Comment: And disable automatic member folder creation (in Site Setup>Security, IIRC).

Comment: @JonStahl: That is disabled by default, but yes, you do need to make sure it is *still* disabled.

Comment: Ah, there's nothing particularly special about the folder, then?

Comment: @IainHallam: There is; although it is a normal folder, it has a default view set (the user search form), automatically.